# non-blocking method to return callable result

Tags: java, executorservice

What is the standard method to wait for future.isDone()==true back on the calling thread(main) of the callable?

I tried returning a result on the calling thread(main thread) through an asyncMethod().  The asyncMethod() returns immediately, but before returning, first triggers a process that results in a broadcast intent back to the main thread.  In the main thread i check for future.isDone(), but unfortunately future.isDone() only returns true half the time.

```
       ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Callable<Boolean> callable = new Callable<Boolean>(){
            public Boolean call() {
                Boolean result = doSomething();
                callbackAsync();  //calls an async method that returns immediately, but will trigger a broadcast intent back to main thread
                return result;
            }
        };

       new broadCastReceiver() { ///back on main thread
       ...
           case ACTION_CALLABLE_COMPLETE:
               if (future.isDone())   // not always true...
                       future.get();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CompletionService` to receive the futures as soon as they are ready. Here is an example with your code

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
CompletionService<Boolean> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(pool);

Callable<Boolean> callable = new Callable<Boolean>(){
    public Boolean call() {
        Boolean result = true;
        //callbackAsync();  //calls an async method that returns immediately, but will trigger a broadcast intent back to main thread
        return result;
    }
};

completionService.submit(callable);

new broadCastReceiver() { ///back on main thread
    .....
    Future<Boolean> future = completionService.take(); //Will wait for future to complete and return the first completed future   
    case ACTION_CALLABLE_COMPLETE: future.get();
```